# execution header not found C++ in mac command line developer tools

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, parallel-processing, c++17

I am using Mac OS Catalina and bundled c++ compiler in command line developer tools. While executing the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>
int main()
{

    std::vector<int> Vec
    { 4, 3, 5, 2, 6, 1 };

    sort(std::execution::par, begin(Vec), end(Vec));
    for (const auto &x: Vec)
    {
        std:: cout << x << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the error:
`g++ --std=c++17 sort.cpp  sort.cpp:25:10: fatal error: 'execution' file not found 1 error generated.`

I am using the c++ 17 version. Later I installed brew gcc version 9 also and the same story. I can't use the parallel execution.

Comment: `sort.cpp:25:10` usually means: in file sort.cpp at line 25 at column 10.  The code you posted does not have 25 lines.  If the code is exactly as posted try looking for un-printable characters after the last `}`

Comment: Try using `std::sort`, maybe also `std::begin` and `std::end`, or using `Vec.begin()` instead

Comment: Did you find out the answer? Having the same issue on Mac